# find and print particular line from list of filename and line number

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have a file `input.txt` which contains multiple filename in the below format.
`FILENAME_DATE_LINENUMBER` , the `input.txt` contains many such filenames.
**The filename itself has precisely 5 underscore**.

```
FILE_NAME_1.DAT_20180123_4
FILE_NAME_2.DAT_20180123_5
FILE_NAME_3.DAT_20180123_6
FILE_NAME_4.DAT_20180123_7
```

All files are present in sub directory as `input.txt`. I want to parse `input.txt` , iterate through each filename and print FILENAME and the specified line number ( from the FILENAME ) to `output.txt`

I understand that sed or awk will be used , and below command can do the job.

```
awk 'FNR==LINENUMBER {print FILENAME, $0}' *.txt >output.txt
```

But how can i iterate through the file `input.txt` and find the FILENAME and extract LINENUMBER from FILENAME to `output.txt`

The FILENAME specified in `input.txt` can in one of the sub directories where `input.txt` is located. There can be only one file with FILENAME in input.txt inside one of the sub directory ( one level ) form the `input.txt` location.

```
DIR
├── input.txt
│   ├── DIR1
│   │   ├── FILE_NAME_1.DAT
│   ├── DIR2
│   │   ├── FILE_NAME_2.DAT
│   ├── DIR3
│   │   ├── FILE_NAME_3.DAT
```

In `output.txt` it should be printed as

```
FILENAME
LINE( Extracted from FILENAME present in input.txt )
```

Comment: With such questions you should always give example output. You want `FILE1.DAT_20180123_4` transformed into `FILE1.DAT 4`?

Comment: @shubhamdeodia, your output should be `FILENAME LINE(under number) ` - update your question

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest , thank you. I have updated.

Comment: @shubhamdeodia, ok, can we assume that all files `FILE*.DAT...` are in the same directory as `input.txt` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest , no they are in the sub directories ( one level down ) from where input.txt is and we don't even know the name of sub directory.

Comment: How deep could the subdirectory structure be? What if there is more than one FILE1.DAT (for example) found, or is there only one in the whole subtree?

Comment: @shubhamdeodia, but you said *one level down*, so at least you may specify a parent directory. What's is the actual directory structure?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest , sorry , i have updated the directory structure in the question.

Comment: @shubhamdeodia, how many records could file `input.txt` contain (approximately)?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest , at max 100. Also, fileName may contain more than 3 underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                   

do_one() {
    # two args: $1=filename_no_dir $2=line_number                                             
    # Find the single filename                                                                
    eval file=*"/$1"
    echo $1
    # $. == line number                                                                       
    perl -ne 'chomp; $.=='"$2"' and print "LINE($_)\n"' $file
}
export -f do_one

# Generate som test data                                                                      
parallel 'mkdir DIR{}; seq 100 110 >DIR{}/FILE_NAME_{}.DAT' ::: {1..4}

# Test input.txt                                                                              
cat <<EOF |                                                                                   
FILE_NAME_1.DAT_20180123_4                                                                    
FILE_NAME_2.DAT_20180123_5                                                                    
FILE_NAME_3.DAT_20180123_6                                                                    
FILE_NAME_4.DAT_20180123_7                                                                    
EOF                                                                                           
  # Remove _YYYYMMDD.* to get filename, and .*_ to get line number                            
  parallel do_one '{= s/_201\d\d\d\d\d.*// =}' '{= s/.*_// =}'
```

Output:

```
FILE_NAME_1.DAT
LINE(103)
FILE_NAME_2.DAT
LINE(104)
FILE_NAME_3.DAT
LINE(105)
FILE_NAME_4.DAT
LINE(106)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:> awk -F_ '{ print $1; print $3; }' inputfile
FILE1.DAT
4
FILE2.DAT
5
FILE3.DAT
6
FILE4.DAT
7
```

Comment: what if  FILE2.DAT is in nested directory from where inputfile.txt is. I mean we don't know the relative path for FILE2.DAT from inputfile and we don't even have the exact name of subdirectory.

Comment: @shubhamdeodia Are you complaining to me about your input data...?

Comment: I am sorry , my question was a little confusing, I have corrected it. I want to find the FILENAME in input.txt and then find line number in FILENAME and print it to putput.txt

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly,

```
while IFS=_ read -r filename unuseddate linenum
do
  printf "%s\n" "$filename"
  sed -n "${linenum}{p;q}" */"$filename"
done < input.txt > output.txt
```

This reads one line at a time from input.txt, splitting the line into 3 parts based on the underscore. It prints the filename then fires off a sed command that (by default prints nothing) and then on the specified line number, prints the line and quits that invocation of sed. The location of the filename should be in one of the immediate subdirectories of the current directory.

All of the output is then redirected to output.txt.

Comment: Hi , Is there a way we can tell the script to select last occurrence of underscore for line Number instead of 3rd occurrence because filename may contain more than 3 underscore.

Comment: Not this script, because I based it on your sample input. You should really post representative data in your question in order to get usable answers.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this script works perfectly with 3 underscore. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Complex solution with GNU **`parallel`** + **`find`** + **`awk`**:

Let's say each input file has a content similar to the following:

```
cat DIR1/FILE1.DAT_20180123_4
FILE1 a 
FILE1 b 
FILE1 c 
FILE1 d 
FILE1 e 
FILE1 f 
FILE1 g
```

---

So, by the above scheme, the 2nd line in file `FILE2.DAT_20180123_5` would be `FILE2 b` and the 7th line in file `FILE4.DAT_20180123_7` - `FILE4 g`.
Assume `input.txt` file is the same as in the question.

The job:

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/($(paste -s -d'|' input.txt))" \
| parallel -j0 "awk -v n="{=s/.*_//=}" -v fn="{/}" \
               'NR==n{ print fn,\$0; exit }' {}" > output.txt
```

The final `output.txt` contents:

```
$ cat output.txt 
FILE4.DAT_20180123_7 FILE4 g
FILE3.DAT_20180123_6 FILE3 f 
FILE1.DAT_20180123_4 FILE1 d 
FILE2.DAT_20180123_5 FILE2 e
```

Comment: Hi , but the fileName itself has some underscore , to be specific 5 underscore.

Comment: @shubhamdeodia, elaborate your file name convention: should all the files be ended with `.DAT` only?

Comment: Yes, they all end with .DAT , but I can't install GNU parallel in my Linux distro. Don't have the privileges.

Comment: @shubhamdeodia, the main problem is in your `input.txt` - it should have include full filenames not basenames. So reconsider your `input.txt` scheme and your life will be easier

Comment: @shubhamdeodia Are the reasons covered on http://oletange.blogspot.dk/2013/04/why-not-install-gnu-parallel.html If not, please elaborate.